# How can I stop browser from submitting a form in javascript?

Tags: javascript

When this code running my form is submit and not end submit.

How can stop submit when count is 0?

```
function btnCheck_Click() {
  var count = parseInt(61);
  myCounter = setInterval(function () {
  if (count > 0)
    count--;
    elem.html( count );
  }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can most easily cancel a form submit from within the submit handler, so with something like this:

```html
<form onsubmit="return validateClickCount()" />
```

Now if you have a function `validateClickCount`, the submit action will be canceled when it returns `false`.

```js
function validateClickCount() {
  return false;
}
```

With this in place, you just need to change your `btnCheck_Click`/interval-callback to decrease a global counter and then check that counter in the `validateClickCount`.

```js
var count = 61;
function btnCheck_Click() {
  myCounter = setInterval(function () {
    if (count > 0)
      count--;
      elem.html( count );
  }, 1000);
}

function validateClickCount() {
  return count > 0;
}
```

If you're looking for more information, I suggest looking at this question and the answers too: [How do I cancel form submission in submit button onclick event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227043/how-do-i-cancel-form-submission-in-submit-button-onclick-event)