# jQuery - Change number of arguments based on function parameter

Tags: jquery

Sorry bad title. I've got a simple form with an input field and I know that every time I submit the form the number of arguments that gets passed is one. When the argument of one gets passed **reload** gets evaluated to true and if **reload** is true the page get's refreshed. The problem is that what if I don't want to refresh the page. What if I want **reload** to get evaluated to false in certain instances. Is there some parameter I can pass into the userInput function that would evaluate certain scenarios to false? Any ideas? I learn best by code samples, please include where applicable. I also have a fiddle going here:

http://jsfiddle.net/JuG48/2/

```
<form id="myForm">
  <input id="address" name="address" value="address">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

function userInput(userLocation, input){
  $('#myForm').on('submit', function(e){
  reload = arguments.length > 1 ? arguments[1] : true;
  if (reload) location.reload();
  console.log(reload);
});
}

$(document).ready(function () {    
    userInput();
});
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't get what you want..

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if there's a way I can pass in a parameter to the function that will return false in certain instances. So could I do something like **userInput(false)** That's just a guess though.

Comment: I think u have to set some  cond where it will false inside the function like : function somemethod(p1, p2) { reload =(arguments.length<1 ? false: (arguments.length > 1 ? arguments[1] : true); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your case the quickest solution is garlic.js

http://garlicjs.org/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( 'form' ).garlic();
</script>
```

a native solution will be

```
$('#myForm').submit(function () {
 reload = arguments.length > 1 ? arguments[1] : true;
 if (reload) location.reload();
 console.log(reload);
 e.preventdefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks @ProllyGeek! I was looking for more of a native solution which seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The page will automatically refresh or follow the post action url when a form is submitted. I'm confused about the line that conditionally reloads the page. Have you tried returning `false` in the `submit` handler to control the page reload? [How do I cancel form submission in submit button onclick event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227043/how-do-i-cancel-form-submission-in-submit-button-onclick-event)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want no argument in userInput () method call to be reload = false so do this way ...

```
function userInput(userLocation, input){
$('#myForm').on('submit', function(e){

   reload = (userLocation==undefined && input==undefined)? false 
   :(arguments.length > 1 ? arguments[1] : true);       
   console.log(reload);
   if (reload) location.reload();
   else return false;      
  });
}

$(document).ready(function () {    
userInput();
 });
```

**[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JuG48/5/)**