# Disable form submission if a field has invalid values

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I have a html form with multiple textboxes. Each textbox can accept only integers.

I am using `dojo NumberTextBox` to validate this.
But the problem is, even if a textbox is in error, only an error tooltip is displayed but the user can still press the `submit` button.

Is there a way to disable the submit button if any textbox is in error?

Comment: Are the elements wrapped in a dojo Form or just a regular HTML form? The dojo form uses the kind of validation you want.

Comment: Changed to dojo form and it worked.
Thanks Chris..

Comment: duplicate question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227043/how-do-i-cancel-form-submission-in-submit-button-onclick-event   (how to prevent submission).

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a custom submit button.

```
<button onClick='submitForm("NAME OF FORM")' value='Submit'>

<Script>
function submitForm(name) {
  var bad = 0;
 for(Loop through values) {
  if(isNaN(num)) {
     bad = 1;
  }
 }
 if(bad==0) {
    document.forms[name].submit();
 }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is one way, but Chris's solution worked for me.