# force option from <select> drop down before submit form

Tags: php, forms

I want the user to be forced to select any option in the drop down apart from the default "selected" option

here is my drop down menu code;

```
    <form><label>Select Tank:</label>
<select class="text2" name="tank" id="mySelect">
          <option value="0" selected="selected">Select your tank</option>
          <option value="4"> Tank#1 </option>
          <option value="9"> Tank#2 </option>
          <option value="21"> Tank#3 </option>
          <option value="34"> Tank#4 </option>
      </select>
<input type="button" id="btncheck" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

and here is my java;

```
$('#btncheck').click(function(){
     if ($("#mySelect ")[0].selectedIndex <= 0) {
         alert("Please select a tank from the menu!");
                return false;
                }
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/36JZL/41/

for some reason it validates correctly but form isnt submitted.

Comment: you want the php to stop processing? or form submittal?

Comment: best option i think would be for form to submit but return error and not actually run the INSERT into database part of the page. Will link code now.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/wytVN6gv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with jQuery on client side but its not a good option to validate things on client side.

PasteBin: http://jsbin.com/zer/1

```
<form id="myForm">
<label>Select Tank:</label><br />
    <select class="text" name="tank" id="tankSelector">
        <option value="All" selected="selected"> Select Tank </option>
        <?QUERY HERE TO PULL AND LOOP FROM DATABASE?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"> <?php echo $row->description; ?> </option>
        <? END LOOP ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#myForm').submit(function(e){
            if($('#tankSelector').val() == 'All') {
                alert('Select tank!');
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i used your script to no avail... but i did try some of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/36JZL/41/ but form isnt submitting now when i select a different drop down?

Comment: Remove whole else clause, you have errors there and use input type submit. <input type="submit" id="btncheck" value="Submit"/>

Comment: Or use: else {
  $("form").submit(); 
 }

Answer (score 0):

```
<label>Select Tank:</label><br />
<select class="text" id="seltank" name="tank">
    <option value="All" selected="selected"> Select Tank </option>
</select>
```

in the client side click event of your submit button add some javascript to check the value of your drop down.

```
if(document.getElementById("seltank").value == "All")
{
     //put some code to alert the user or show error
    return false; //this should prevent your post
}
```

Similar post is here [How do I cancel form submission in submit button onclick event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227043/how-do-i-cancel-form-submission-in-submit-button-onclick-event)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do:

```
<select class="text2" name="tank" id="mySelect">
     <option></option>
     <option value="4"> Tank#1 </option>
     <option value="9"> Tank#2 </option>
     <option value="21"> Tank#3 </option>
     <option value="34"> Tank#4 </option>
</select>
```

If the user hits submit without making a selection, they will be prompted to select an option automatically.  The limitation is that you don't get a pretty little "select an option" placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help. Im yet to find a stable answer

If using php:

```
$val = $_POST['select_input'];  <--- works fine
```

or
$val = $request->select_input <---- can be problematic

On Html

```
<select id="select_input" name="select_input" >                                                                                           
    <option value="0">Pending</option>                                                                                                                                                                                    
    <option value="1">Approved</option>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    <option value="0" selected>Pending</option>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
</select>
```