# how to display popup message in asp.net button using vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want the message box popup and after display user click OK then it will redirect to the target page. The problem is it will directly go to the target page without display the popup message. I have tried all coding that I've found but still doesn't function. Please check my coding if there is something missing tq.

```
Try
        ......

        da1.Fill(ds, "Student")
        da2.Fill(ds, "StudentAccess")
        Validate()

        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "AlertMessageBox", "alert('Your Data Has Been Saved, Thank You for Register.');", True)

        Response.Redirect("Verify.aspx")
        con.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "AlertMessageBox", "alert('Error');", True)
    End Try
```

Comment: ClientScript will not work for this, you need to use Modal popups and on there you can give a button, on its click event it will Response.Redirect to your "Verify.aspx" page.

Comment: A. i would downvote your post but i need 125 rep B. don't use msgbox/aert, they are blocked on IE versions after 6.x or something, and other browsers. C. use a custom usercontrol, or some JS client side that pops a div on the page, with a button, which submits the form, which then gets validated, etc...

Comment: @porkchop In most browsers, including IE 6.0 and above, a JavaScript `alert` is allowed under default settings. It is worth mentioning, however, that most browsers include an option to turn JavaScript off. [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) helps in this situation.

Comment: Perhaps the answers to this question will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227043/how-do-i-cancel-form-submission-in-submit-button-onclick-event

Comment: @Sean, my apologies then, been a while since i did asp.net dev. i would use the form method though.