# Handling Enter key on Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have been working on Web Forms for many months, but today I encountered a problem.

I have e.g. 2 buttons on form `Save`. Next, when a user fills out the form and presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it should trigger the SAVE button.

I tried a lot like

```
this.Page.Form.DefaultButton = btnSave.UniqueID; 
this.Page.Form.DefaultFocus = btnSave.ClientID;
```

but it didn't work.

Please help me on this. I have tried many codes, but none of them actually worked.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // 2 lines of code, for setting Save as a default
    // button upon page loading so hitting Enter will
    // trigger SAVE button.
    this.Page.Form.DefaultButton = btnSave.UniqueID;
    this.Page.Form.DefaultFocus = btnSave.ClientID;

    if (Session.Count <= 0)
    {
        Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
    }

    lblMsgPopUp.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: This looks correct to me, and I have been able to make your code work in Chrome and Firefox.  What specific error(s) or problem(s) do you get?  What "didn't work"?

Comment: when i click on textbox than it takes away focus from save button.

Comment: Well,  yes, that is to be expected.  Setting the default (i.e. initial) focus on `btnSave` won't prevent the focus from shifting to a text box or other input that is clicked.  What happens when you press Enter?

Comment: it submits value upon pressing

Comment: That is also to be expected.  It sounds like this is working exactly like it should.  What do you want it to do differently?

Comment: see, problem is that i have 4 textboxes, e.g. i enter text into first textbox and accidently press enter than it triggers Enter, i want it to trigger enter upon reaching last textbox only

Comment: This assumes that the 4th text box will always be the last one in which the user provides input.  It sounds like you would be better off using client-side validation to cancel a submit when Enter is pressed prematurely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you have is fine.  I checked it in Chrome and Firefox so as not to miss anything by just reading it.

If you want `btnSave` to only trigger a save when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed *and* the form is complete, I suggest using client-side validation to ensure that the form is complete, cancel the submit and alert the user if it is not etcetera.

See [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4227043/1810429) about client-side validation and cancellation of a submit if you need help with that.