# JS validation and PHP validation

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation

This is my site  [Liquid Layouts](http://www.liquidlayouts.com) .

The issue i am having is on the [register](http://www.liquidlayouts.com/registration/register.php) and page, the validation with JS before PHP.
I never learned JS, i went PHP route after CSS and every time i put in a JS validation, it will either still proceed to PHP after error or just not pass on to the PHP page if no errors are detected.

All i really want is a definitive answer on what will allow the JS validation to kill process on error and pass to PHP process if all is right

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site! This is a bad question. I recommend you read [the entire Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and head back when you have

Comment: As an aside, I hope that you plan to enhance your site and learn to be a web developer before you start offering web development services.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I cancel form submission in submit button onclick event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227043/how-do-i-cancel-form-submission-in-submit-button-onclick-event)

Comment: how so  Michael Deluca

Comment: The site looks like something that would be spam and created in the 90's.

Comment: not much of a critique, is my coding bad?? maybe the design is, but im looking for constructive criticism.

Comment: The reason why this isn't a good question for Stack Overflow - which someone should have explained already! - is that it refers readers to an external link. Once you have fixed the problem, the question loses its value, since readers can no longer see what you were referring to. Questions therefore must be self-contained for that reason.

Comment: "Branding will help progress ur business" - it would probably be best to switch that to 'your' - txtspk on a marketing website will chase a good number of customers away. The word 'separate' is misspelled a couple of times too.

Comment: thanks for clearing that up, i will make sure i post code next time and not use an outside link as the source

Comment: thanks halfer, good looking out

Comment: (No probs. If you wish to communicate with individuals here, use the at-symbol followed by their username. You have tab completion, so type the 'at' followed by a letter, and press tab. This alerts the relevant user with a notification icon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prevent the default action.
In this case, you need to prevent de form submit
If you are using jquery, you can do something like this

```
$("form.contact").on("submit", function(e){
     e.preventDefault();

     //do your validation
     if(valid){
          $("form.contact").submit();
     }
});
```

The submit action (PHP) will occur if js validation is true.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the jQuery validate plugin, this is an easy script that will allow you to do what you want. If you are unsure about jQuery, it's just a JavaScript library.