# validate if 1 to 3 chekboxes are cheked but with different id

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, checkbox

I have a little problem here, so I have a form, inside I have 8 chekboxes in one section 
all are with images above them so if the user click over the image to check their specific chekboxes to .

Here is the code of my chekboxex and the script to validate them:

```js
function logotype() {
  var group = document.newlogo.ltype;
  for (var i=0; i<group.length; i++) {
    if (group[i].checked)
      break;
  }
  if (i==group.length)
    return alert("Please select 1 to 3 Logo Types");
}
```

```html
<div class="thumb1" >
  <label for="letter"><img class="img" src="images/my2.jpg"  /></label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chk"   name="ltype[]"  id="letter" value="letter" />
  <hr>
  <p><strong>Letter Mark Logo</strong></p>
</div>
<div class="thumb1">
  <label for="emblerm"><img class="img" src="images/my3.jpg"  /></label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="chk"   name="ltype[]" id="emblerm" value="emblerm" />
  <hr>
  <p><strong>Emblerm Logo</strong></p>
</div>
```

As you may see the `id="ltype"` if i make all my checkboxes with the same `id` it works with validating but after this my checkboxes can't be checked from images because `for="anothername"` if i put ltype it makes all jujst select one field . .

So the question is: Can I somehow validate the checkboxes based on their class names so that at least 1 to three checkboxes are checked when submit?

Comment: *"if i make all my checkboxes with the same id"* - don't do this, `id` should be unique in a document. If there are multiple elements with same `id` in a document, it might cause unexpected results...

Comment: `<center>` is deprecated, use CSS `text-align: center` instead. `id`s must be unique. `document.newlogo.ltype` isn't standard, I think you meant `document.forms.newlogo.elements.ltype`. And please write clearly (e.g. use "because", not "cuz"), I fixed what I could but I found some parts unintelligible (e.g "pyt").

Comment: i didn't know that guys thanks its my first time on form processing and validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) method to access the checkboxes using classname, and validate them as follows:

```
function logotype() {
  var failure = true,
  count =0,
  group = document.getElementsByClassName("chk");
  for (var i=0; i<group.length; i++) {
    if (group[i].checked)
      count++;
    if(count>=3){
      failure =false;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (failure){
     alert("Please select 1 to 3 Logo Types");
     return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: @T J one question with this code structure it brings me the alert even if i check one or three of the options when on submit and then the process goes on but the alert displays what should i do ?

Comment: @NewLogo what do you mean "* then the process goes on but the alert displays"* - what is the process..? are you submitting a `<form>`?

Comment: @T J the form get submitted and i get the data after i click on the ok of the alert. i mean when the fields are all filled right and i click on the submit button it shows me the Please select 1 to 3 Logo Types" and after clicking ok the form get submitted as it should

Comment: @NewLogo If you want to prevent the `<form>` submission, change your `<form>` to `<form onsubmit="return logotype()"/>
` and retrn `false`  from the function, as shown in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4227096/2333214).

Comment: @T J no its not the case that i want to prevent the form submission but the alert shows up even when the checkboxes are checked right sorry for my delay

Comment: @NewLogo  I think i misunderstood the question - the answer checks whether at least 3 checkboxes are checked or not... What exactly do you mean by *"so that at least 1 to three checkboxes are checked "* - doesn't make sense...what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: @T J we misunderstand each other look i want at least 1 checkbox to be checked and maximum 3 of 8 can be checkable. This mean if one is checked then it should be ok , but if 4 than not this is the main idea

Comment: Yes this is what i wanted thank you very much for your great support @T J