# adds number when typed in input field and answer it automatically how

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to make a calculater type form which gives addition of entered number without submit of form 
currently i made this code
'

```
<html>
<body>
<p>Click the button to calculate x.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<br/>
<br/>Enter first number:
<input type="text" id="txt1" name="text1">Enter second number:
<input type="text" id="txt2" name="text2">
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
 function myFunction() {
    var y = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
    var z = document.getElementById("txt2").value;
    var x = +y + +z;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  }
  window.onload =myFunction() ;
</script>
```

thanks in advance pls help me ...'

Comment: what is your back end language? java web application.. ?

Comment: @NomeshDeSilva why is the back end language relevant to a client-side question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227043/how-do-i-cancel-form-submission-in-submit-button-onclick-event Simply return false from your function. There are various improvements to your code that can be made but that solves the form submission question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will want to attach event listeners to the input. I have done that in a function triggered from `window.onload` by targeting a class name `calc`. You also want to `parseFloat` the values.

This is to give you a starting point and show how to trigger the function without having to submit/click.

```js
function myFunction() {
var y = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt1").value);
var z = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txt2").value);
var x = y+z;
// If x = NaN empty variable x
if(isNaN(parseFloat(x))){x='';}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
window.onload=function(){
var inputs=document.getElementsByClassName('calc');
  for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
    // Listen for input > Call MyFunction
   inputs[i].addEventListener('input',myFunction,false);
  }
};
```

```html
Enter first number:<input type="text" class="calc" id="txt1" name="text1">
Enter second number:<input type="text" class="calc" id="txt2" name="text2">
<p id="demo"></p>
```

If you have any questions about the source code above please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what you here want to do is when you change any of the value of Textbox, answer should be displayed. Try using Jquery for this. 
hint: use .keypress() 
https://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Comment: Impossible to achieve this in `javaScript` ?

Comment: jQuery is basically cross-platform JavaScript library.

Comment: There are projects which are developed without using `jQuery`. There is nothing which could be achieved using `jQuery` but not using `Core javaScript`