# Print out form with Javascript - Text disappears right away

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having some trouble with my javascript, it's supposed to print out whatever information you write into the form, and it does, but then it disappears right away. Can't figure out what I've done wrong here, please help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Javascript</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Personal Data</h1>

    <p>Fill in your name in the form below:</p>
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            First name <input id="fname" type="text"><br>
            Last name <input id="lname" type="text"><br>
            Age <input id="age" type="number" value="0"><br>
            <button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button><br>
            <p id="demo"></p>
            <script>
                function myFunction() {
                    var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
                    var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
                    var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<p>My name is " + fname + " " + lname + " and I am " + age + " years old!</p>";
                }
            </script>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A button without specified type submits the form as a default action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`button` elements are, by default, `type="submit"` ([yes, really](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-button-element)). Since your button is in a `form`, it submits the form. Since the form has no explicit `action` attribute, it submits itself to the current page URL, refreshing the page.

Add `type="button"` to the button, or remove the `form`.

Answer (score 1):

This button **submits** the form. Adding a `return false` there, prevents this submission from happening. So your code should be:

```
function myFunction() {
    var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
    var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
    var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<p>My name is " + fname + " " + lname + " and I am " + age + " years old!</p>";
    return false;
}
```

And in the HTML:

```
<button onclick="return myFunction()">Click</button><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>`

This is causing your form to submit (which causes your javascript console to clear).

You can either `return false;` from `myFunction()` or you can do `onclick="myFunction(); return false;` or cancel the event or any number of other things.

[How do I cancel form submission in submit button onclick event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227043/how-do-i-cancel-form-submission-in-submit-button-onclick-event)

[How to prevent form from being submitted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350247/how-to-prevent-form-from-being-submitted)

You can also add `type="button"` to the button or eliminate the `<form>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <form>
            <fieldset>
                First name <input id="fname" type="text"><br>
                Last name <input id="lname" type="text"><br>
                Age <input id="age" type="number" value="0"><br>
                <button onclick="return myFunction()">Click</button><br>
                <p id="demo"></p>
                <script>
                    function myFunction() {
                        var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
                        var lname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
                        var fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
                        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<p>My name is " + fname + " " + lname + " and I am " + age + " years old!</p>";
return false;
                    }
                </script>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

use return to prevent it from submitting form

Answer (score 0):

Inside your form, the buttons are considered "submit" type by default. To prevent this use type="button" with buttons.

Hope this helps :)