# Can you dynamically load form paramaters

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have worked some recapthca into my web form and want to maintain the client side form validation.  As the form currently is

```
  <form action="ajax/ajax_repSubTesting.php" method="POST" name="submitform" onSubmit="checkform(this)">
```

checkform() is a series of if/else statements to inform the user that a data field is either blank or not valid.  Problem is that once the submit button is clicked , the checkform is called popping up an error window, and once closed the ajax script is called.

How would I code this so that the form action is dependent on everything in checkform() validated properly?

Comment: The issue is that the Ajax method is not dependent on the result of the checkform function. Show us all of your javascript.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350247/how-to-prevent-form-from-being-submitted

Answer (score 2):

Returning `false` from an inline onsubmit event handler will will cancel the form submission. The checkform function should return false (as appropriate) for invalid form data

```
function checkform () {
   if (!valid) { return false; }
   // ..
}
```

*and* the returned value must be propagated through the inline event handler

```
<form .. onsubmit="return checkform()">
                   ^^^^^^
```

See also

- [How do I cancel form submission in submit button onclick event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227043/how-do-i-cancel-form-submission-in-submit-button-onclick-event)
- [How to prevent form from being submitted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350247/how-to-prevent-form-from-being-submitted?lq=1)

(Also, 'ajax' is normally called via XHR, not form submission.)

Comment: return checkform(); solved this as checkform returns false if an error is caught. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

try adding id to the submit button and yhe form itself.
Then at the beginning of the validation method add 
event.preventDefault(); 
Which will cancel the form submition.

Then at  the end of the validation method if the form is valid add the next jQuery method:
$('form').submit() it will trigger form submition.