# using window.open() has the effect of submitting form prematurely

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a web-form written in ASp.Net MVC5 which is used to gather some details from the user.  However, before I get them to submit the form, I want them to have the option to look at another web-page (in a new window or tab) which gives them more information if they need it prior to submitting the page. To that end, on the web-form, I have a form with the following buttons:

```
<form action="/Application/MyAction" method="post" id="myForm">
    // various fields ...
    <button onclick="getMoreInfo()">More Information</button>
    <button type="button">Submit Form</button>
</form>
```

Then, at the bottom of the page I have the following javascript defined:

```
<script>
function getMoreInfo()
{
    var urlToUse = 'http://some-other-page.html';
    window.open(urlToUse);
    return false; // trying to stop the form submission from occurring
}
</script>
```

My problem is that when this "More Information" button is clicked, it has the effect of submitting the form [which I don't want to do yet] - since there is a separate submit button for doing that task.  Is there a way to use a button to jump to another page without actually submitting the current form?

thanks heaps,

David.

Comment: It's not `window.open`, it's the clicked button. Add the `type="button"` to that button as well as the button below has it.

Comment: use `event.preventDefault();` as the first line of the function

Answer (score 0):

I found that answer #3 at this question helped me:

[How do I cancel form submission in submit button onclick event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227043/how-do-i-cancel-form-submission-in-submit-button-onclick-event)

My solution was to change the code thus:

I changed the button code to look like this:

```
<form action="/Application/MyAction" method="post" id="myForm">
    // various fields ...
    <button id="moreInformationButton" >More Information</button>
    <button type="button">Submit Form</button>
</form>
```

And then I changed the javascript to look like this:

```
$("#moreInformationButton").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();  // This stops the submit form being triggered
    var urlToUse = 'http://some-other-page.html';
    window.open(urlToUse);  // open the help page
});
```

This allowed me to open up another window or tab with more information without actually submitting the form.

Comment: You could have just put the `event.preventDefault();` as the first line in your previous function.