# Javascript prevent reload in case of return false

Tags: javascript, html

I have my html page with a form that, onsubmit call a javascript function for check some value:

html:

```
<form onsubmit="isempty();" role="form">
```

isempty():

```
function isempty() {
    var r_1;
    var r_2;
    var r_3;


    r_1 = document.getElementById("t_select");
    r_2 = document.getElementById("t_descr");
    r_3 = document.getElementById("t_terms");

    if((r_1.value == "Please select...") || (r_2.value == "") || (r_3.checked == false)) {
        alert("Please fill in all the form fields including the terms of use to proceed with the publication");
        return false;
    } else {
        //OK
    }

}
```

All works done, the only problem is that in case of check fail, page display alert then reload, cleaning all preview inserted data.
How can I display alert in case of failure and then freeze page (no reload)?

So many thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227043/how-do-i-cancel-form-submission-in-submit-button-onclick-event

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript code to stop form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486/javascript-code-to-stop-form-submission)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return a value in the onSubmit event to control the submission.

```
<form onsubmit="return isempty();" role="form">
```

And let the function return true or false to do the controlling.

Answer (score 1):

take the event argument use it to prevent the default behavior of the browser in this case you'll not loose your data

```
 isEmpty(event) {
   event.preventDefault()
   // do whatever you were to do now
}
```