# JavaScript - check if form is filled

Tags: javascript, html, forms

We have to make a website as a project. We have a form with text inputs, dropdown and checkboxes. I already have the code for checking if there's at least one checkbox selected. But when the other fields aren't filled the script still continues. I want to check first if the other fields are filled before it checks the checkboxes. And then continue to the next page. I couldn't find any help so im begging you guys to help me.

Code:

```
<!-- Angabenfelder -->
    <div class="w3-container" style="font-family:Arial">
        <br>
        <div class="w3-card-4">
            <div class="w3-container" style="background-color: maroon">
                <h1 style="color: white; text-align: center">Bitte geben Sie folgende Daten ein:</h1>
            </div>
            <form method="post" name="eintragen_schueler" class="w3-container">
                <div style="color: maroon">
                    <p>
                    <b>Vorname</b>
                    <input class="w3-input w3-border w3-round" type="text" id="vorname" name="vorname" required>

                    <p>
                    <b>Nachname</b>
                    <input class="w3-input w3-border w3-round" type="text" id="nachname" name="nachname" required>

                    <p>
                    <b>Geburtsdatum</b>
                    <input class="w3-input w3-border w3-round" type="date" id="geburtsdatum" name="geburtsdatum" required>

                    <p>
                    <b>E-Mail</b>
                    <input class="w3-input w3-border w3-round" type="email" id="email" name="email" required>

                    <p>
                    <b>Schulstufe</b>
                    <select class="w3-select w3-border w3-round" id="schulstufe" name="schulstufe" required>
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Schulstufe auswählen</option>
                        <option value="1">Mittelschule</option>
                        <option value="2">Oberschule</option>
                    </select>
                    </p>
                    <br>
                    <b><div style="font-size: 20px">In welchen Fach benötigen Sie Hilfe?</div></b>
                </div>
                <p>
                <input class="w3-check" id="mat" type="checkbox" name="fach" value="mat"> <label>Mathematik</label>
                <p>
                <input class="w3-check" type="checkbox" name="fach" value="deu"> <label>Deutsch</label>
                <p>
                <input class="w3-check" type="checkbox" name="fach" value="eng"> <label>Englisch</label>
                <p>
                <input class="w3-check" type="checkbox" name="fach" value="ita"> <label>Italienisch</label>
                <p>
                <input class="w3-check" type="checkbox" name="fach" value="che"> <label>Chemie</label>
                <p>
                <input class="w3-check" type="checkbox" name="fach" value="phy"> <label>Physik</label>
                <p>
                <input class="w3-check" type="checkbox" name="fach" value="inf"> <label>Informatik / IKT</label>
                <br>
                <div class="w3-container w3-center">
                    <p>
                    <button class="w3-button w3-mobile w3-highway-red w3-border" name="btn_senden" onclick="check()">Senden</button>
                    <button type="button" class="w3-button w3-mobile w3-highway-red w3-border" onclick="history.go(-1)">Zurück</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>

    <script>
        function check()
        {
            var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName("fach");
            var okay = false;

            for(var i = 0, l = checkboxes.length; i < l; i++)
            {
                if(checkboxes[i].checked)
                {
                    okay = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (okay)
            {
                window.location.assign("eintragung_erfolgreich.html")
            }
            else alert("Bitte wählen Sie mindestens ein Fach.");
        }
    </script>
```

I can't find anything online that helps me.

Comment: You don't call `check()` anywhere. `check()` must return true/false when used `onSubmit="return check()"`. Button to "Zurück" must have `type="button"`, otherwise it will also submit form

Comment: @Justinas I just forgot to put check() to onclick="check()" when I copy pasted it. I changed the button type thx.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I cancel form submission in submit button onclick event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227043/how-do-i-cancel-form-submission-in-submit-button-onclick-event)

Answer (score 0):

I added an extra checkbox `<input type="checkbox" name="fachsum" required>` that will be checked by the function `update_fach()` if one or more of the fachs are checked. You can hide it if you like or add an event listener to it that prevents default.

When you click `Senden` the form will be submitted if all required fields are OK (including `fachsum`). If none of the fachs are checked (following that `fachsum` is not checked), there is an event listener on `fachsum` that will display the alert and stop further "checking" of the form by calling `e.preventDefault()`.

I also added the submit URL as an action attribute on `<form>`.

```js
const fach_input = document.forms.eintragen_schueler.fach;
const fach_sum = document.forms.eintragen_schueler.fachsum;

// sumit event listener is just for testing here on ST
document.forms.eintragen_schueler.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('submit');
});

const update_fach = e => {
  let cheched = [...fach_input].filter(input => input.checked == true).length;
  if (cheched == 0) {
    fach_sum.checked = false;
  } else {
    fach_sum.checked = true;
  }
};

fach_sum.addEventListener('invalid', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("Bitte wählen Sie mindestens ein Fach.");
}, true);

fach_input.forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('click', update_fach);
});
```

```html
<!-- Angabenfelder -->
<div class="w3-container" style="font-family:Arial">
  <br>
  <div class="w3-card-4">
    <div class="w3-container" style="background-color: maroon">
      <h1 style="color: white; text-align: center">Bitte geben Sie folgende Daten ein:</h1>
    </div>
    <form method="post" name="eintragen_schueler" action="eintragung_erfolgreich.html" class="w3-container">
      <div style="color: maroon">
        <p>
          <b>Vorname</b>
          <input class="w3-input w3-border w3-round" type="text" id="vorname" name="vorname" required>
        </p>
        <p>
          <b>Nachname</b>
          <input class="w3-input w3-border w3-round" type="text" id="nachname" name="nachname" required>
        </p>
        <p>
          <b>Geburtsdatum</b>
          <input class="w3-input w3-border w3-round" type="date" id="geburtsdatum" name="geburtsdatum" required>
        </p>
        <p>
          <b>E-Mail</b>
          <input class="w3-input w3-border w3-round" type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
        </p>
        <p>
          <b>Schulstufe</b>
          <select class="w3-select w3-border w3-round" id="schulstufe" name="schulstufe" required>
            <option value="" disabled selected>Schulstufe auswählen</option>
            <option value="1">Mittelschule</option>
            <option value="2">Oberschule</option>
          </select>
        </p>
        <br>
        <b><div style="font-size: 20px">In welchen Fach benötigen Sie Hilfe?</div></b>
      </div>
      <input type="checkbox" name="fachsum" required>
      <p>
        <input class="w3-check" id="mat" type="checkbox" name="fach" value="mat"> <label>Mathematik</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input class="w3-check" type="checkbox" name="fach" value="deu"> <label>Deutsch</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input class="w3-check" type="checkbox" name="fach" value="eng"> <label>Englisch</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input class="w3-check" type="checkbox" name="fach" value="ita"> <label>Italienisch</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input class="w3-check" type="checkbox" name="fach" value="che"> <label>Chemie</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input class="w3-check" type="checkbox" name="fach" value="phy"> <label>Physik</label>
      </p>
      <p>
        <input class="w3-check" type="checkbox" name="fach" value="inf"> <label>Informatik / IKT</label>
      </p>
      <br>
      <div class="w3-container w3-center">
        <button class="w3-button w3-mobile w3-highway-red w3-border" name="btn_senden">Senden</button>
        <button type="button" class="w3-button w3-mobile w3-highway-red w3-border" onclick="history.go(-1)">Zurück</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```